# Limits that approach zero.

Tags: calculus

I am so confused on this concept.

When

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x-1 &, x < 0\\ 2x-1 &, x \geqslant 0, \end{cases}$$

what is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? What exactly does your problem say?

Comment: lim f(x), f(x)={x-1 x<0}

Answer (score 4):

I think it is useful too look at this graphically first.

[image: graph]

Now that you can see this graphic, lets consider the geometric interpretation of the limit. If I have the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$, them I am essentially asking: What is the value of $f(x)$ as $x$ gets closer and closer to zero?

If we look at the above graph, that is pretty strait forward, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to negative one.

In math, however, we like to be more rigorous, so we must now define the limit algebraically. To take a limit we choose an x value arbitrarily close to the desired x value (i.e. the number you are limiting to). If we approach the same value from the positive and negative sides, them no matter where you approach the desired $x$ from, you will be approaching the same value, so you have no need for explicitly saying "from the positive side" or "from the negative side." In notation we say 
$$(( \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} = y) \wedge ( \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} = y) )\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to 0} = y $$
or "If the limits from both the positive side and the negative side equal y, then the limit equals y"

For piece wise functions it is slightly more complicated, we must first see which function applies on the negative side of the limit, and which one applies on the positive side, then take the limit for both and see if we arrive at the same value, otherwise the limit does not exist.

So here we take the limit from the negative side:

The equation of the function for the negative side is $f(x) = x- 1$, which is defined for zero, so we can just plug in zero (if it were not defined we would plug in $.5$ then $.24$ et cetera). $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = (0)-1 = -1$$

Now the positive side:

The equation of the function for the positive side is $f(x) = 2x- 1$, which is defined for zero, so we can just plug in zero. $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 2(0)-1 = -1$$

and so we find that:
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = -1 = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x)$$
and so, by our definition before, we see that:
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = -1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Find the two limits $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}f(x).$ Keep in mind that $f(x)$ has a different formula when $x>0$ than it does when $x<0$.